# I want to do Daily ATM cash forecasting

Tags: time-series

I have a data for ATM transaction on a daily basis and this data represent a seasonal variation in weekend and holidays.

data structure like this

trans_date  tot_amount  Weekend Holiday_flag
01/10/2013  164800  0   0
02/10/2013  205900  0   1
03/10/2013  215600  0   0
04/10/2013  228600  0   0
05/10/2013  410200  1   0
I used arima() function in R to forecast the next one month data but I am not getting better forecast.

I am confusing to capture seasonal variation in my data.

I have to select the ARIMA order from ACF and PACF plot but I have some confusion to capture seasonal order from this graph.

So please advise me how can I select the right ARIMA model for my data

Comment: Refer to this answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58657/time-series-forecasting-with-daily-data-arima-with-regressor

Comment: Can you share 3-4 weeks of the dataset. I'm curious myself.

Comment: @sergie Rodionov this is the link for data set.you refer sheet one for training data and sheet 2 for validation data........................................... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LJhxzfpMkeCwLf129D9-q5ZkGhISqrDQWCw30UE9TE/pubhtml

Comment: hi Sergie,have you done any work on that data for cash forecasting..??